# How to display JS values on my HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get three different dynamic timezone clocks on my site. i've got the following js code which i found on this site (saved as myClocks.js and included on the header of my html site):

```
var clock1 = new Date();
var clock2 = new Date();
var clock3 = new Date();
clock2.setHours(clock2.getHours() + 3);
clock3.setHours(clock3.getHours() - 5);
clock1.getUTCHours();
clock1.getUTCMinutes();
clock1.getUTCSeconds();
clock2.getUTCHours();
clock2.getUTCMinutes();
clock2.getUTCSeconds();
clock3.getUTCHours();
clock3.getUTCMinutes();
clock3.getUTCSeconds();
```

How do I code the "display" to show it anywhere I want on my HTML page? For example as an id called `clocks`, to look like the following:

> New York: 02:12:02 Paris: 17:01:24 Moscow: 22:23:42

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: you should learn DOM manipulation. for a start, you can just do `document.write(clock1);`

Comment: Bear in mind that UTC doesn't take daylight saving time changes into account

Comment: I'm overwhelmed with the fast responses and how helpful everyone is arround here. However what i am really looking for is for the world clocks to be dynamic and not static. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`innerHTML`](http://javascript.about.com/library/bldom06.htm) is what you need. Try something like:

```
window.onload = function(){ // It is important to wait till DOM is ready!
   var clocks_str = clock3.getUTCHours()+" "+ clock3.getUTCMinutes()+" "+clock3.getUTCSeconds();
   document.getElementById("clocks").innerHTML = clocks_str ;
}
```

And if you want it dynamic , use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) method , like this:

```
 var clocks_interval;
 var clocks_box;

 window.onload = startClocks;

 function startClocks(){
    clocks_box = document.getElementById("clocks");
    clocks_interval = setInterval(updateClocks , 1000); // 1000 means 1 second
 }

 function updateClocks (){
    var clocks_str = clock3.getUTCHours()+" "+ clock3.getUTCMinutes()+" "+clock3.getUTCSeconds();
    clocks_box.innerHTML = clocks_str ;
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the help. is there any way to avoid making the clocks static? (no page refresh required to see time changing)

Answer (score 1):

```
<html><head></head><body>
<script language="javascript">
ourDate = new Date();
document.write("The time and date at your computer's location is: "
+ ourDate.toLocaleString() 
+ ".<br/>");
document.write("The time zone offset between local time and GMT is " 
+ ourDate.getTimezoneOffset() 
+ " minutes.<br/>");
document.write("The time and date (GMT) is: " 
+ ourDate.toGMTString() 
+ ".<br/>");
</script>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a div or other HTML and use "innerHTML".

```
document.getElementById("clocks").innerHTML = clock1.getUTCHours();
```